# Set response data from external JS script

Tags: javascript

I have this script

```
<script>
function loadJS(src, callback) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = src;
    s.async = true;
    s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
        var state = s.readyState;
        if (!callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
            callback.done = true;
            callback();
        }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
loadJS('/script/script.js', function() { 
    // put your code here to run after script is loaded
});
</script>
```

And I can't figure out how can I get response data from the script I'm trying to load.

Basically, this script contains a function that does something and then returns some value.

I know that in jQuery analog in would be just `data` argument in `getScript` function, but I only have native JS here.

What and where should I add to get response data in my script?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your script contains a function declared in a global scope, you can simply include this script and then execute any function / access any member from this script:

After your script has been loaded and executed, you can work with it just like with a simple script which is a part of your current document.

Here is a demo which loads jQuery script from Google CDN and then outputs jQuery version (which is a part of jQuery library):

```js
function loadJS(src, callback) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = src;
  s.async = true;
  s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
    var state = s.readyState;
    if (!callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
      callback.done = true;
      callback();
    }
  };
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}

console.log("typeof jQuery: " + typeof jQuery); // jQuery not loaded
loadJS("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
  console.log("typeof jQuery: " + typeof jQuery + ", version = " + jQuery.fn.jquery); // jQuery has been loaded
});
```